# Digital Ocean shared file system over cluster of node.js servers?

Tags: database, node.js, digital-ocean

Is there some way to have a shared file system over a cluster of node js servers on digital ocean without establishing a separate database?

Answer (score 0):

If it is only a filesystem that you want then you could take a look at amazon S3, it is more expensive than running your own filesystem but much easier managed.
Otherwise Mongo can act as a file serving database and it can be distributed among your servers. If you are running node I suppose you could be using Mongo.